# Reduce gear box and DC motor noise

Tags: dc-motor, noise, mechanical

I'm working on a project where I use DC motor and gearbox to reduce the speed and get a higher torque.

The problem is, when the project sit, for example on a table, the noise is amplified. (with transferred vibration). Which is great for the musical box but a real pain for the DC motor and gears noise.

Do you have any idea on how I can reduce the noise of this ?

[image]

(If you think StackExchange EE is not the correct place, let me know where I can ask this and I'll delete the post)

Comment: Nice bit of work - sorry - just admiring the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to replace or rebuild the mechanicals you already have:

- lubricate the gears with some grease to cushion the teeth. Go with something very viscous so it doesn't drip off.
- attach the motor assembly to something very heavy. By making it heavier, the force of the vibrations will cause less movement, and thus less sound.
- attach the motor + something heavy assembly to your music box with something soft and light, like rubber. The interface between the hard, heavy thing and the soft rubbery thing will be very poor at coupling vibrational energy, confining most of it within the motor assembly and preventing it from coupling into the music box which will act as a soundboard.

Answer (score 2):

Lose the gear box and go with belts and pulleys.  It will be quieter.  Just use V-groove instead of toothed belts/chains.